# Oracle ojdbc driver returns float result for integer values in NUMBER type column

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have Oracle 10g database and Java application based on Spring 4.1.6 framework, which extracts some data out of Oracle. I faced an issue, that ojdbc driver returns `float` result for integer values in `NUMBER` type column. ResultSet metadata identifies object type as BigDecimal.

Column definition:
`MINUTES NUMBER` with no precision and scale
Actual value is "70"

I have checked with Oracle 10, 11 and 12 ojdbc drivers and every time the same `Java code returns "70.0000000000000000000000000000000000002` as value of this column in a row. I have also checked with Oracle SQL Developer 4.1.1 and it shows the same incorrect float value.

Toad however shows correct value "70".

Any ideas ? Please note again: **This issue is reproduced in Oracle SQL Developer 4.1.1 **

Update - Java code below :

```
for (int j = 1; j <= count; j++) {
 Object field = resultSet.getObject(j);
 if (field != null) { 
      bufferedWriter.write(field.toString());
 }
 if (j < count) { 
       bufferedWriter.write(delimiter); 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Could you post the Java code you use for retrieving the data -- perhaps you're _reading_ the value as `float` or `double`, instead of `int`?

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer 4.1.1 shows the same float value. However:
 `for (int j = 1; j <= count; j++) {
            Object field = resultSet.getObject(j);
            if (field != null) {
                        bufferedWriter.write(field.toString());
            }
            if (j < count) {
                bufferedWriter.write(delimiter);
            }
        }`

Comment: Could you try running `resultSet.getInt(j)`, for the given `j` that holds the integer value? When using [`resultSet.getObject(j)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28int%29), the value gets implicitly cast into an object that represents the default data type for SQL `NUMBER`, i.e. probably `BigDecimal`. (This may or may not be causing the rounding/precision error.)

Comment: Please add the code in the question not in comment. Try editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

The NUMBER datatype stores fixed and floating-point numbers. When you specify numeric fields, it is a good idea to specify the precision and scale. This provides extra integrity checking on input.

NUMBER (precision, scale)

But, if a precision is not specified the column stores values as given i.e. maximum scale and maximum precision(up to 38 digits of precision). As given, it will behave as `Float` in java. Example of sample input given below :

```
Input              Stored As
7,456,123.89       7456123.89
```

A lot more info at [Oracle Data Type](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832).

Especially this section :

> **Internal Numeric Format**
>
> Oracle Database stores numeric data in variable-length format. Each value is stored in scientific notation, with 1 byte used to store the exponent and up to 20 bytes to store the mantissa. The resulting value is limited to 38 digits of precision. Oracle Database does not store leading and trailing zeros. For example, the number 412 is stored in a format similar to 4.12 x 102, with 1 byte used to store the exponent(2) and 2 bytes used to store the three significant digits of the mantissa(4,1,2). Negative numbers include the sign in their length.

So, If you want to store `Integer` value only, change the column definition to NUMBER(10,0) which is as close as you can get to `Integer` in java. Otherwise, strip the trailing zeros from `BigDecimal`

Code edited :

```
for (int j = 1; j <= count; j++) {
 BigDecimal field = (BigDecimal)resultSet.getObject(j);
 if (field != null) { 
    bufferedWriter.write(field.stripTrailingZeros().toString());
 }
 if (j < count) { 
     bufferedWriter.write(delimiter); 
 } 
}
```

Or Explicitly cast to Integer (to lose decimal part)

```
for (int j = 1; j <= count; j++) {
     Integer field = (Integer)resultSet.getObject(j);
     if (field != null) { 
         bufferedWriter.write(field.toString());
     }
     if (j < count) { 
         bufferedWriter.write(delimiter); 
     } 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I forgot to add one important note, object type in Java is BigDecimal. Java based Oracle SQL developer show the same float value, whilst Dell Toad for Oracle shows correct integer value "70"

Comment: Thanks again, though I have read all possible information about Oracle data types and conversion to Java classes before asking this question. And all these topics do no explain why SQLPlus command line client and Dell Toad return correct integer value "70" whilst Java based clients my code and Oracle SQL Developer return "70.0000000000000000000000000000000000002", though "70" value was saved in DB. My opinion it is a bug in ojdbc data mappings.

Comment: I have checked your solution with explicit casting to BigDecimal. Unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: May be but am not sure and regarding solution given above, its not working probably because of presence of 2 at the end. You should probably explicitly cast it to Integer instead of BigDecimal to get rid of decimal part ( as I mentioned earlier).

Comment: As of now the easiest workaround I found is to change SQL statement and do "select ROUND(column)" instead of "select column". I will try to contact Oracle support and discuss this issue.